# Unified Memory and Streams in C

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am trying to use streams with CUDA 6 and unified memory in C. My previous stream implementation was looking like this :

```
for(x=0; x<DSIZE; x+=N*2){

 gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(array_d0, array_h+x, N*sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream0));
 gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(array_d1, array_h+x+N, N*sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream1));


gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(data_d0, data_h, wrap->size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream0));
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(data_d1, data_h, wrap->size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream1));

searchGPUModified<<<N/128,128,0,stream0>>>(data_d0, array_d0, out_d0 );
searchGPUModified<<<N/128,128,0,stream1>>>(data_d1, array_d1, out_d1);

gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(out_h+x, out_d0 , N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream0));
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(out_h+x+N, out_d1 ,N *  sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream1));

}
```

but I cannot find an example of streams and unified memory, using the same technique, where chuncks of data are sent to the GPU. I am thus wondering if there is a way to do this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should read [section J.2.2](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-coherency-hd) of the programming guide (and preferably all of appendix J).

With Unified Memory, memory allocated using `cudaMallocManaged` is by default attached to all streams ("global") and we must modify this in order to make effective use of streams, e.g. for compute/copy overlap.  We can do this with the `cudaStreamAttachMemAsync` function as described in section J.2.2.3  By associating each memory "chunk" with a stream in this fashion, the UM subsystem can make intelligent decisions about when to transfer each data item.

The following example demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DSIZE 1048576
#define DWAIT 100000ULL
#define nTPB 256

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

typedef int mytype;

__global__ void mykernel(mytype *data){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < DSIZE) data[idx] = 1;
  unsigned long long int tstart = clock64();
  while (clock64() < tstart + DWAIT);
}

int main(){

  mytype *data1, *data2, *data3;
  cudaStream_t stream1, stream2, stream3;
  cudaMallocManaged(&data1, DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMallocManaged(&data2, DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMallocManaged(&data3, DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMallocManaged fail");
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream1);
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream2);
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream3);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaStreamCreate fail");
  cudaStreamAttachMemAsync(stream1, data1);
  cudaStreamAttachMemAsync(stream2, data2);
  cudaStreamAttachMemAsync(stream3, data3);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaStreamAttach fail");
  memset(data1, 0, DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  memset(data2, 0, DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  memset(data3, 0, DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  mykernel<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB, 0, stream1>>>(data1);
  mykernel<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB, 0, stream2>>>(data2);
  mykernel<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB, 0, stream3>>>(data3);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++){
    if (data1[i] != 1) {printf("data1 mismatch at %d, should be: %d, was: %d\n", i, 1, data1[i]); return 1;}
    if (data2[i] != 1) {printf("data2 mismatch at %d, should be: %d, was: %d\n", i, 1, data2[i]); return 1;}
    if (data3[i] != 1) {printf("data3 mismatch at %d, should be: %d, was: %d\n", i, 1, data3[i]); return 1;}
    }
  printf("Success!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The above program creates a kernel that runs artificially long using `clock64()`, so as to give us a simulated opportunity for compute/copy overlap (simulating a compute-intensive kernel).  We are launching 3 instances of this kernel, each instance operating on a separate "chunk" of data.

When we profile the above program, the following is seen:

[image]
First, note that the 3rd kernel launch is highlighted in yellow, and it begins *immediately* after the second kernel launch highlighted in purple.  The actual `cudaLaunch` runtime API event that launches this 3rd kernel is indicated in the runtime API line by the mouse pointer, also highlighted in yellow (and is preceded by the cudaLaunch events for the first 2 kernels).  Since this launch happens during execution of the first kernel, and there is no intervening "empty space" from that point until the start of the 3rd kernel, we can observe that the transfer of the data for the 3rd kernel launch (i.e. `data3`) occurred *while kernels 1 and 2 were executing*.  Therefore we have effective overlap of copy and compute.  (We could make a similar observation about kernel 2).

Although I haven't shown it here, if we omit the `cudaStreamAttachMemAsync` lines, the program still compiles and runs correctly, but if we profile it, we observe a different relationship between the cudaLaunch events and the kernels.  The overall profile looks similar, and the kernels are executing back to back, but the entire cudaLaunch process now begins and ends before the first kernel begins executing, and there are no cudaLaunch events during the kernel execution.  This indicates that (since all the cudaMallocManaged memory is global) all of the data transfers are taking place prior to the first kernel launch.  The program has no way to associate a "global" allocation with any particular kernel, so all such allocated memory must be transferred before the first kernel launch (even though that kernel is only using `data1`).

Comment: The image fails to load. Can Robert re-upload the picture? Thank in advance.

Comment: The image is still there and is loading fine.  I think the problem is probably on your end, with your internet service or machine.